# Wrap full filepath in double quotes

Tags: vba, excel, ftp

I have a file which I need to FTP using VBA and I have figured most part of it except last one where I need to insert `"` in the file name but not able to do.

```
csvPath = "C:\Users\10613527\Desktop\test\"
sWorkingDirectory = csvPath
sFileToSend = "Price_Change_10-08-15 20-35-49.csv"

iFreeFile = FreeFile
Open sWorkingDirectory & FTP_BATCH_FILE_NAME For Output As #iFreeFile
Print #iFreeFile, "open " & FTP_ADDRESS
Print #iFreeFile, FTP_USERID
Print #iFreeFile, FTP_PASSWORD
Print #iFreeFile, "ASCII"
Print #iFreeFile, "put " & sWorkingDirectory & sFileToSend
Print #iFreeFile, "dir"
Close #iFreeFile

'Shell command the FTP file to the server
Shell "ftp -i -w:20480 -s:" & sWorkingDirectory & FTP_BATCH_FILE_NAME
```

> In the above code , I get the error that the file is not found.

[image]

The reason is that the file path and name is not in `""`, for example this code is writing another script file and executing that one.

**So it needs to be**

```
open ftp path
username
password 
ASCII
put "C:\Users\10613527\Desktop\test\Price_Change_10-08-15 20-35-49.csv"
dir
```

**and not**

```
open ftp path
username
password 
ASCII
put C:\Users\10613527\Desktop\test\Price_Change_10-08-15 20-35-49.csv
dir
```

Notice the `" "` in the **PUT** statement, I have no idea how to place them there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `""` to escape `"` in a vb string.

So

```
Print #iFreeFile, "put """ & sWorkingDirectory & sFileToSend & """"
```

Comment: Wow sometimes i am amazed by my dumbness. I tried this and not the triple quotes  Print #iFreeFile, "put "" & sWorkingDirectory & sFileToSend & """

Comment: You can also use Chr$(34) to represent "